# Static Google Maps not showing some custom markers

Tags: google-maps

I am generating a static google map using this [here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x640&maptype=hybrid&markers=icon:http://tracker.galetti.co.za/images/brochuremarkers/Pin1.png%7C-34.04348538373925,18.588438034057617&markers=icon:http://tracker.galetti.co.za/images/brochuremarkers/Pin2.png%7C-34.04749470252471,18.623242378234863&markers=icon:http://tracker.galetti.co.za/images/brochuremarkers/Pin3.png%7C-34.0503482263598,18.621675968170166&markers=icon:http://tracker.galetti.co.za/images/brochuremarkers/Pin4.png%7C-34.03571512214461,18.609766960144043&markers=icon:http://tracker.galetti.co.za/images/brochuremarkers/Pin5.png%7C-34.065654275427256,18.611912727355957&markers=icon:http://tracker.galetti.co.za/images/brochuremarkers/Pin6.png%7C-34.0526594213,18.600969314&markers=icon:http://tracker.galetti.co.za/images/brochuremarkers/Pin7.png%7C-34.049761528,18.62006664276123&markers=icon:http://tracker.galetti.co.za/images/brochuremarkers/Pin8.png%7C-34.04114676,18.586013500213653)

Markers from number 6 are not showing the custom icon but the default one. I can confirm that the icon are there on the server, and if I remove markers 1-5, the rest will then show. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Can you show us your code (the one where you are populating the markers)?

Comment: But that is irrelevent to the question? The link has the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit of 5 custom markers:

> the Static Maps service allows **up to five unique custom icons** per
>   request. Note that each of these unique icons may be used multiple
>   times within the static map.